# Woocommerce product archive merge

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm wanting to inject some custom field items into the woocommerce product archive page (based on category). An example is: on an archive page of all necklaces I want to show a grid of links to the necklaces as well as some supporting images (models wearing necklaces etc) which can be injected at random points in the array but they don't have to be links.

I've succeeded in pulling in the images I want, though they're currently in a separate array and are grouped at the top of the page before the loop. So how can I merge the woocommerce product loop array and my custom image array?

I'm grabbing the custom fields I've set up at the top of my `archive-product.php`:

```
// Get ACF Image Repeater
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;  

$modelimages = get_field('model_images', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);

// If there are model images for the this product category
if($modelimages):

    // Create empty model image array
    $models = array();
    while( have_rows('model_images', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id) ): the_row(); 

        // Add URLs of model pix to the array           
        $models[] = get_sub_field('file')['sizes']['medium'];

    endwhile;

endif;
```

The above just creates an array of image urls, which is working fine. I want to 'inject' each if these items at random points into the woocommerce product loop further down in `archive-product.php`:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

So how can I create an output loop or array combining both products and non-product images, for example :

Product 1,
Product 2,
non-product(image),
Product 3,
Product 4,
Product 5,
non-product(image)
Product 6
etc....

If there is a plugin that anyone knows of that already achieves this then that would be great.

-- edit ---

I've somehow got this to to work. Not sure it's the best solution but in case it helps anyone else: in your `archive-product.php` I replaced the loop with the following

```
// I have set an Advanced Custom Fields Repeater File(model_images) for product categories
// Get current archive category
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;  

// Get related product category images from ACF
$modelimages = get_field('model_images', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);

// Create empty models array
$models = array();

// If there are model images
if($modelimages):   

    while( have_rows('model_images', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id) ): the_row(); 

        // Add URLs of model image files to the array           
        $models[] = get_sub_field('image')['sizes']['medium'];

    endwhile;

endif;


if ( get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ) { // If on a product taxonomy archive (category or tag)
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //all
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ),
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => get_query_var( 'term' ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
// make an array of the products
$products = get_posts( $args );

// merge the arrays of products and models
$merge = array_merge($products, $models);

// shuffle the merged array
$keys = array_keys($merge); 
shuffle($keys); 
$random = array(); 
foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[$key] = $merge[$key]; 
};

foreach($random as $r) {

    if($r->post_type !== 'product') :
        // do layout stuff with the model picture
    else : 
        // it's a product
        $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'product',
           'p'              => $r->ID
        );            
        $product_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $product_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $product_query->have_posts() ) : $product_query->the_post();
               // use the woocommerce template for products
               wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;  

    endif;

endforeach;
```

It's probably all kinds of ugly, but at least it's working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's considered polite around here to post the part of your attempted code where you're stuck or facing unexpected behavior. You may consider editing your question and adding some more detail as to what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry @PavoDive, still new to this so don't know the etiquette.

Comment: It's just written... "How to Ask [...] Provide details. Share your research."

Comment: If you don't modify the query itself I think you could run into pagination problems. If the model images don't link to anything, I'd probably approach this by finding a way to assign terms to the media library images (which i am sure exists). Then you could filter `pre_get_posts` to maybe add media images to the query. Though I will admit to having already run into great difficulty getting the WooCommerce shop query to merge with other product types because of custom things going on in WooCommerce not because it can't be done in WordPress.